# data-abide marks all fields as invalid

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for(@building_shared_space, data: {abide:''}) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :room_type, 'Room Type' %>
    <%= f.text_field :room_type, placeholder: 'Room Type', required: '' %>
    <%= content_tag(:small, 'Please enter a room type', class: 'error') %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :default -%>
    <%= f.check_box :default %>
  </div>
  ...
```

When I submit, it correctly highlights and displays a warning next to Room Type. However, it also makes the other form labels red. Why is this happening?

I'm using Foundation and Rails 4.

Comment: Well. Can you show the development log file data what is has?  Submit the form again and see what it is printing the log file and paste those here..

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the `<small class="error">` ... `</small>` work, it must be a sibling of the input.  While it may look like putting the element *after* the input, which would be a sibling, would work, the code is affecting -all- siblings.  (Which makes sense in 20/20 hind-sight.)

The wording of the documentation, can be interpreted (especially with little sleep) that the wrapping `<div>` is just for the sake of the example. However, having a parent element for the input control and the error message is mandatory.  `<DIV>` just works incredibly well.

The Custom Named Patterns code example actually doesn't show a wrapping element. It also, to be fair, doesn't show an error message element. But this can mislead one to think the wrapping `<div>` is superfluous and just for the sake of explaining what's going on, rather than being a necessary component of making the right tree structure in the DOM to isolate validation behaviors.

Comment: In short make sure your input is wrapped in a `<div></div>`.